# Returning a result based on multiple ranges?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a spreadsheet where I want to populate a cell to indicate if three conditions are met from ranges of other cells.  Users must complete one of two Interest Badges (B4:C4), one of four Skills Builders (D4:G4) and 3 hours of other activities (H4).   Cells are populated with a "1" if complete, a "0" if not complete and are populated as IF functions referring to other worksheets within the same file.

In cell I4, I want it to put a "Y" if all three conditions are met.  But to leave it blank if one or more conditions are not.

I am googling but struggling with exactly how to word my question on google and I have tried various methods.  So far, I've had no luck.

Is this possible?  If so can anyone help please?

Comment: Not completely clear, but seems like a fairly simple application of `IF,  AND` and `SUM`. What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I know, it's hard to explain without being able to attach a picture unfortunately.  My most recent effort was this:

=IF(SUM(B4:C4)>0,AND IF(SUM(D4:G4)>0,AND IF(SUM(H4)>0,"Y","N")))

Which returns a response "FALSE" in I4.  However, it should be a "Y" as all three conditions are met.  This is progress compare to yesterday's attempts which are hard to recall because I tried so many options!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attempt you refer to in the comments seems like it is trying to use `AND` as a logical operator rather than a function. `AND(Condition1,Condition2,Condition3` makes sense but `Condition1 AND Condition2 AND Condition3` does not. Also, `IF` isn't typically used as part of a condition so much as the function which does something in response to a condition. `IF(AND(...` is common but `AND(IF(...` is relatively rare.

The formula that you are looking for seems to be:

```
=IF(AND(SUM(B4:C4)>=1,SUM(D4:G4)>=1,H4 >=3),"Y","")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  That has answered the question I had and I've now got it working.

I discovered that the IF functions I was using to refer to other worksheets in order to populate this one had speech marks around the numbers so reading them as a string and not an integer =IF('Interest Badges'!E4>2,"1","0").  So the SUM was not working as it didn't see it as a number.  Removing the speech marks and using your formula has done the job.  

I really appreciate your help!